# weka attribute selection with accuracy reports

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka, feature-selection

I am using weka attribute selection filter on a dataset with string attributes. Currently I am using ClassifierSubsetEval or WrapperSubsetEval in combination with different Classifiers and different search methods (often geneticSearch). I want to **output an arff-file** with selected attributes, but also I need a **report of how good** this attribute subset performs. Best would be for every time a new subset is evaluated but it would be also ok if I would at least have one evaluation when the selection is finished. 
How can I accomplish this using the terminal?